# How to access DbContext in .NET 6 minimal API Program.cs

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, minimal-apis

I am trying to call EF Core methods on application startup in my Program.cs file, using the .NET 6 minimal API template and get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot resolve scoped service 'Server.Infrastructure.DbContexts.AppDbContext' from root provider.'

```
// ************** Build Web Application **************

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseNpgsql(configuration.GetConnectionString("AppDb:Postgres")));

// ...

// **************** Web Application *****************

var app = builder.Build();

var dbContext = app.Services.GetService<AppDbContext>(); // error thrown here

if (dbContext != null)
{
    dbContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();
    dbContext.Database.Migrate();
}

// ...
```

With earlier versions of .NET Core I am aware I can get the DbContext in the `Configure` method, but how would I get the service with this approach?

Comment: What is the error thrown ? Have you tried to create a scope first  `app.Services.CreateScope()` and then call `GetService` on the scope ?

Comment: https://github.com/davidfowl/CommunityStandUpMinimalAPI/blob/main/TodoApi/Program.cs

Answer (score 27):

[Scoped](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#scoped) services require scope to be resolved. You can create scope via [`ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.CreateScope`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.serviceproviderserviceextensions.createscope?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0):

```cs
using(var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();
    // use context
}
```

Comment: But why has this changed?

Comment: @ataraxia what exactly?

Comment: From OP's original code to your solution when trying to obtain a DbContext?

Comment: @ataraxia in .NET 6 new alternative approach to hosting was introduced and it is used by default in new templates. So original code was never working.

Comment: [See the docs on the new 'minimal APIs' for more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: Damn all these changes... I spent so much time googling on setting up asp.net core 6 with entity framework core 6. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> default implementation can also be used. I suspect that it creates a scope if it does not exist yet.