# .NET Core : best pratice to set up IssuerSigningKey with key stored in database

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API project where the initialization code is in `Program.cs` and there I need to set up JWT authentication, and in there I need to set up `IssuerSigningKey` which is fetched from SQL database since I am using the .NET Core / EF `dataprotection` lib to generate and renew the key automatically. the problem I am facing is that I have to create new `DbContext` manually instead of being able to use dependency injection, following is my code and wonder if it is a legit way to achieve my goal here

```
var contextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .UseSqlServer(connectionString, x => x.UseNetTopologySuite())
    .Options;

OperationalStoreOptions storeOptions = new OperationalStoreOptions();

IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> operationalStoreOptions = Options.Create(storeOptions);

var context = new ApplicationDbContext(contextOptions, operationalStoreOptions);

SymmetricSecurityKey securitykey = null;
var keyDb = context.DataProtectionKeys.FirstOrDefault();

if (keyDb == null || keyDb.Xml == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentException("security key missing!");
}
else
{
    XDocument keyDoc = XDocument.Parse(keyDb.Xml);
    string keyAsStr = keyDoc.Descendants("value").First().ToString();
    byte[] keyAsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(keyAsStr);
    securitykey = SymmetricSecurityKey(keyAsBytes);
}

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
   options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
   options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
   options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
                                             ValidateIssuer = true,
                                             ValidateAudience = true,
                                             ValidateLifetime = true,
                                             ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                                             ValidIssuer = "****",
                                             ValidAudience = "****",
                                             IssuerSigningKey = securitykey 
                                       };
        });
```

Comment: What you have is fine.  maybe abstract it in a method call to make it more legible. DI isn't always a must.  It's 11 lines of code that aren't being reused everywhere. If you really wanna inject it you can. Do something like this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70386368/how-to-access-dbcontext-in-net-6-minimal-api-program-cs

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your ApplicationDbContext does with that second parameter, but I think it could be done in a simple way. My idea is to add a new class and a new interface to your Models:

```
public interface IMyService
{
    IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> GetOptions();
}
public class MyService : IMyService
{        
    public IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> GetOptions()
    {
        OperationalStoreOptions storeOptions = new OperationalStoreOptions();
        return Options.Create(storeOptions);            
    }
}
```

Then you can add the DI in your **Startup.cs**:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString, x => x.UseNetTopologySuite()));
services.AddScoped<IMyService, MyService>();
```

At last, let's not forget to add the references in your ApplicationDbContext constructor:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> _operationalStoreOptions;

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options, IMyService operationalStoreOptions) : base(options)
    {
        _operationalStoreOptions = operationalStoreOptions.GetOptions();
    }

    ....your code (DbSet,...)
}
```

Finally, in your HomeController, you can use the **_context**:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{                
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your input, but I think there is some misunderstanding here, it is not about the second parameter for the dbcontext (it can be one parameter only, but it is not the main problem here), but rather creating a new dbcontext instance in Program.cs and use it to fetch a security key from database and assign it to builder configuration before app is generated - var app = builder.Build();